# Is it possible to link to the same page with different CSS conditions active, depending on which Link I clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have three different Links that all lead to the same page. But I need the page to load with different CSS settings (depending on which link was clicked, certain elements should be hidden on the new page).

Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Which framework are you using? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use the `:target` pseudo-class to do so.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target):

> The **:target** CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (*the target element*) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

With `target`, you click a link, like `page.html#some-condition`, and in your `CSS`, listen for that condition. When the `id` matches the hash in the address bar, you have a match and the target is met.

```html
<a href="#some-condition">A link</a>
<div id="some-condition"></div>
```

```css
#some-condition:target {
  /* style appropriately */
}
```

Here's a quick demo. In this case, the links contain the `id`s, but as demonstrated above, you can structure things however you'd like.

```css
#red:target ~ .result {
  background-color: red;
}

#blue:target ~ .result {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green:target ~ .result {
  background-color: green;
}

.result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}
```

```html
<a id="red" href="#red">Red</a>
<a id="blue" href="#blue">Blue</a>
<a id="green" href="#green">Green</a>

<div class="result"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/0v8eosrm/4/)

Comment: Thank you! But I realized that I have phrased my question badly, after clicking one of these links, a new page opens, however, this new page is the same for all links. What I need is a way to open the new page with different CSS conditions, depending on which link was clicked. 

The new page has certain div elements that I need shown or hidden depending on what link was used to get to the page. I hope that makes it clearer, I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough before.